# What does the orange triangle in the target column of Android Device Chooser window mean?

Tags: android, eclipse, warnings, target

When I launch my Android app with Eclipse, the usual window "Android Device Chooser" appears. I can here choose on which device I want to run my app.

In the target column appears next to my target an orange triangle with an exclamation mark (kind of 'warning') (see the image below)

Does somebody know what it means ?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [this mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-beginners/X7_ktvSxGeA/discussion), that just means you're utilising an optional library and Eclipse can't be sure it's installed on the device. Eclipse knows you're using a compatible version of the API, it's just not sure about the optional extension you're using. So you should be fine, as long as the app works on the phone.

Comment: I think it also might mean that the minSdkVersion you defined in the manifest is bigger than the one you're trying to run the app on.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same exclamation point next to my target but the code complile and run OK. In my opinion the warning appears because the device target has a different API version than project one. In my case the Android project is build with 2.3.3. but my Samsung device has installed 2.3.4

Answer (score 1):

just you need to change the target SDK version from "Google API to Android" from sdk window as attached screens shot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be a result of wrong project properties/dependencies, as desribed in another question on the same subject: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22953719/997940