# Orange triangle in the target column of Android Device Chooser window

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device, google-maps-api-2

When I launch my Android app with Eclipse, the usual window "Android Device Chooser" appears. I can here choose on which device I want to run my app.

In the target column appears next to my target an orange triangle with an exclamation mark (kind of 'warning')

When I search on the internet about this problem I've found this.
[What does the orange triangle in the target column of Android Device Chooser window mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227820/what-does-the-orange-triangle-in-the-target-column-of-android-device-chooser-win)

But the problem is the solution given in this thread doesn't work for me.I'm getting this following error.
"Unfortunately app has stopped".

I've checked that minSdkVersion.
In my app,
minSdkVersion : 8
my device's sdk version is 16

What is the problem?I tried to run simple 'Hello World' app and it works fine.Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you are not using android Google API library,Instead of using Google API library go to Build path and change Android library other than android Google API lib.
Hope this will help you and will remove problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Can you please explain this in more detail?Since I'm new to android app development I can't understand this clearly.

Comment: Got it.I changed it to Google API library but still have the same problem.What do you mean by this?
"go to Build path and change Android library other than android Google API lib."

Comment: Regarding your first comment, Android is developed by Google, but can also be used without any Google services. So the Android platform SDK can be used for developing Android applications. If you however want to use any Google services in your Android Application, you should use the Google API Java Client library.

Comment: go to right click Project ->  build path-> android -> Project build target -> check on Android 4.4.2 /check on Android 4.1.2 ...  instead Google APIs. and this is one of the solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Now that orange triangle has gone but still app doesn't work.

Comment: I added the google play services library under project properties/android as a library.But after sometime it gets a red cross in front of the icon.

Comment: give right lib path you want to  add and keep that library open in your eclipse